# Unable to install Tomcat 5.5

Tags: installation, tomcat5.5

I installed tomcat before but this time when I tried to install after installing Java(JSE,JRE)
am getting a message while installing tomcat-"Failed to install Tomcat service Check your settings and permissions"
Can any one tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Either you already have an existing Tomcat service or you do not have the permissions to install a service.
You could have a look at you services (e.g. control panel, admin tools, services) to see if you already have one installed.

To remove a service, you'll have to edit the registry 
(`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services`) or use a tool like SC (Service Control from the applicable resource kit).

Comment: I formatted my pc after that I tried to install then I got this message, any way I tried the way you gave but no use same message. I removed the registry.

Comment: Ah !! Also make sure that TEMP and TMP variable point to a folder without white space. Such as "C:\TEMP".  This is an early bug.  Do that in the control panel, system, advanced, env variables.